# What does "an example of this" mean and refer to in this explanation?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

In the following explanation:

Irregularity: The quality of not being regular in shape or form, or an example of this.

I don't understand what "an example of this" means. What does "example" mean in this context?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sintinse contains an irregularity.

Comment: In the context given the sentence defines the quality of irregularity apart from an actual case of irregularity. The second part points to an actual example or instance of the irregularity. The term can refer to the irregularity within an example or the example itself as a broader more general term.

Answer (score -2):

From M-W:

Definition of **[irregularity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irregularity)**

> 1: something that is irregular
>
> 2: the quality or state of being irregular

Examples of **irregularity** in a Sentence

> 1: the **irregularity** of his behavior
>
> 2: He is suffering from **irregularity**.

Most uses of **irregularity** will fall under Example 1. That is, they will be examples of the state of not being regular in state or form.